MDF kitchen hardware
i am planning for new house construction and i
want to install MDF kitchen and i have questions:
(i live here in muscat all buildings are concrete)
question 1: is installing upper cabinet with this wall bracket good enough?

the concept of these is very simple and very nice,
but unfortunately these hardware look flimsy.
according to his majesty mr.google these hardware can
withstand 150 kg of load but for one or pair i don't know!
is this true information? can you please confirm is this
the best hardware i can find? no bigger size i can find?
no better alternative that is heavy duty to withstand heavy load?
common sense and logic says to put lightweight things in the top
cabinet so no problem happens and it will not fail. and put heavy items
in the bottom cabinet like crockery, cookware and heavy food ingredients.
also i had an idea to install kitchen doors cup hinges in polished brass or shiny
gold finish stainless steel, but all i can see online is silver color cup hinges.

question 2: are cup hinges available in shiny golden color?
so i don't waste my time looking and searching for something that does not exist.

Try searching for "brass" rather than "gold."

The secret of mounting hardware is to properly mount it into the wall.  Usually into wood studs or concrete anchors.  If MDF cabinets can hold 150kgs, I would be surprised.

I suspect using the correct wall fasteners will be more important than the mounting brackets.
